# My messages repeat many times in node.js/discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I am making an ONUW (One Night Ultimate Werewolf) Discord bot, that allows you to play the game.

For the game, I need a 2 and a half minute timer. I have tried to make one. It runs the command, and then counts down, but it repeats the messages at least 8 times. I expected it to say "Your time has begun! Hop over to ONUW Discussion Voice Channel and tell everyone your role, or try and trick people. Remember, some people may lie so you don't know who they really are!" once, and then after 2.5 minuets, it would say "Times up! Vote for who you want to kill!", again, just once.

Here is the full code file.

```
//required libraries
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

//What to do when the bot starts up.
client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
  client.user.setActivity("with my ding-a-ling")
});

//prefix
var prefix = ("~")

//checks api latency and latency
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;

  if (message.content === prefix + 'ping') {
    message.channel.send(":ping_pong: Pinging...").then((ping) => { ping.edit(`:ping_pong: Pong!\nLatency is ${Math.floor(ping.createdAt - message.createdAt)}\nAPI latency is ${Math.round(client.ping)}ms`); });
  }
}
);

//starts a new game and broadcasts that
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;

  if (message.content === prefix + 'newgame') {
    if (message.member.roles.has("641725420957335562")) {
      client.channels.get('642070729805791232').send("Sending out message....").then((newgame) => { newgame.edit(`Hey, <@&641727807663374345>! A new game is starting. Do ~ready to apply`) })
    }

    client.on('message', message => {
      if (message.author.bot) return;

      if (message.content !== prefix + 'ready') {
        return;
      }

      if (message.content === prefix + 'ready') 
      {message.channel.send(`<@${message.author.id}> is ready!`)
        var roles = Array("Doppelganger", "Werewolf", "Minion", "Mason", "Seer", "Robber", "Troublemaker", "Drunk", "Insomniac", "Villager", "Tanner", "Hunter", "Bartender", "Wolf", "Egotist")
        var role = roles[Math.floor(Math.random() * roles.length)];message.author.send("Your role is..." + role + "!")
      }


      client.on('message', message => {
        if (message.content === prefix + 'begin') {
          function begin() {
            // stuff you want to happen right away
            message.channel.send('The game will begin in...')
            }
          function beginCount() {
            // all the stuff you want to happen after that pause
            message.channel.send('3')
              }
          function beginCount2() {
            message.channel.send('2')
          }
          function beginCount3() {
            message.channel.send('1')
          }
          function nightFall() {
            message.channel.send('Night has fallen!')
          }
          function countdownRun() {
            message.channel.send('~countdown').then(message => { messsage.delete(1000)})
          }
          // call the first chunk of code right away
          begin();
          setTimeout(beginCount, 2000);
          setTimeout(beginCount2, 2000);
          setTimeout(beginCount3, 2000);
          setTimeout(nightFall, 2000);
          setTimeout(countdownRun, 2000);
      };

      client.on('message', message => {
        if (message.content === prefix + 'countdown') {
          function function1() {
            // stuff you want to happen right away
            message.channel.send('Your time has begun! Hop over to ONUW Discussion Voice Channel and tell everyone your role, or try and trick people. Remember, some people may lie so you don\'t know who they really are!')
            }
            function function2() {
              // all the stuff you want to happen after that pause
              message.channel.send('Times up! Vote for who you want to kill!')
              }
              // call the first chunk of code right away
              function1();
              // call the rest of the code and have it execute after 3 seconds
              setTimeout(function2, 150000);
              }
        })
      });
    })}
  });


//logs messages into console
client.on("message", async message => {
  console.log(`${message.author.username} said: ${message.content}`);
});

//Test command if we need it
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;

  if (message.content === prefix + 'test') {
    message.channel.send("test reply")
  }
});



client.login(process.env.TOKEN);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: There is repetition in this code. Would it be an idea to use a `switch(message) {` statement after `client.on('message', message => {` to make the code more readable?

Answer (score 0):

You duplicate the `bot.on ('message')` block too many times, at the same time they are nested in each other.
Try using the command handler approach.

Some guides how it can be create: [Guide 1](https://anidiots.guide/first-bot/a-basic-command-handler) and [Guide 2](https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/#dynamically-reading-command-files)